# Performance Analysis of Ethereum Clients Geth and Parity

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, parity

I want to do performance analysis of Geth and Parity.

I want to run 1000 transactions serially on each client and want to get transaction processing time for each transaction.

How can i get these metrics? Can i get it from the logs or is there any script i need to run?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to write a script to do this. web3.py provides an easy `wait_for_tx` function that  would allow you  to do this in very few lines of code.

Ifnderstand your goal correctly, though, the results will be underwhelming. The performance bottleneck will be the Ethereum network, not a specific client. Each client will be able to process the transaction in under a second, but both will have to wait until the transaction is included in the network before sending the following transactions.

Comment: Can i have a sample code for this.
Basically i want to deploy 1000 transactions on Geth client Environment one by one. Its like once i get success or failure message of earlier transaction my script should deploy the next transaction and if the current transaction is successfully deployed, i need how much it took to process this transaction. So that at the end will plot transactions vs tx processing time for both clients.
Similarly for parity client.